# wordpress add_filer to the_content

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I have the following filter to add a function to the post content:

```
function hook_shrinkshare( $content ){

if(is_single()) {

    $content.= get_social_share();
    return $content;
}}

add_filter('the_content', 'hook_shrinkshare' ,'100');
```

I would like the above to be added to the bottom of the original post content. For some reason it is adding it above.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `$content` passed to the function null/empty?
Try this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'hook_shrinkshare' ,'100', 1);
```

This lets the filter know that the function takes one argument.

Comment: no $content is not null. i have tried the above. It's still showing above the content.

Comment: I'm not sure what the content is. Do you think the reason maybe in the HTML or CSS?

Comment: the content is the the_content();

Comment: Sorry, I mean the content of `get_social_share()`. It may have to do with the HTML and CSS of the content you're trying to append.